# Need help to find the natural response of an RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, remote-control, theory

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

[image: my question]

I am stuck with the point that I am not sure Vo is found as -50v or +50v. Another issue is that Ic(t) is calculated by derivative formulas or another simple formula that is in my attempt on paper. I will add examples and sources of information that I used while solving this question.

Here is my attempt below:

[image]

Here is an example and information:

[image: information]

Consequently, I am confused about how to use formulas in the information given for my question.

Comment: If the bottom node is ground and the switch has been closed for a long time and is suddenly opened at t=0, then the two resistors act as a divider and there will be -50 V on the capacitor (not +50) with reference to that ground at t=0. You should be able to easily see this by remembering the idea of how to create the Thevenin equivalent for a voltage source and a resistor-divider. Once open, the capacitor voltage (at top, referenced to bottom) will decline in magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep an eye out for, especially if just looking for answers and where you do not need to show work in some particular way, is Thevenin equivalents that you can use to replace portions of a circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffu718.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The left and right schematics are equivalent. It's easy to see that, with reference to ground, the voltage on \$V_{_\text{C}}=-50\:\text{V}\$ *after a long time*. What else could it be? (I removed the closed switch.)

Once the switch is open, the situation is now:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV5frR.png)</sup>

Except that you have the initial condition that \$V_{_\text{C}}=-50\:\text{V}\$ at \$t=0\$. Here, you know that the current discharging the capacitor is \$I_{_\text{C}}=\frac{V_{_\text{C}}}{R_2}\$.

The sign is something you need to get used to. It isn't really all that important here, except that it tells you the direction of the current (depending on point of view.) In this case, the conventional current direction (arrow pointing from more positive towards more negative) will be in a clockwise loop direction.

(If it helps you to "see" things, you can always move the ground around. You are free to do that. So you could just set \$V_{_\text{C}}=0\:\text{V}\$ and then rename your earlier ground to something else. Keep your mind flexible, like this.)

Returning to the diagram, and applying KCL:

$$\frac{V_{_\text{C}}}{R_2}+C_1\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_{_\text{C}}=0\:\text{A}$$

This is a standard differential equation found all over the place (like population growth or decline rates):

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_{_\text{C}}=-\frac{1}{R_2\,C_1}V_{_\text{C}}$$

It just says that the rate of change is proportional to the quantity. In this case, if \$k=-\frac{1}{R_2\,C_1}\$ then \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_{_\text{C}}=k\cdot V_{_\text{C}}\$. And you know the initial condition, too (the starting population, etc.) Multiply both sides by \$\text{d}t\$, also dividing both sides by \$V_{_\text{C}}\$, to get \$\frac1{V_{_\text{C}}}\text{d} V_{_\text{C}} = k\,\text{d}t\$. Integrate both sides to find \$\ln\left(V_{_\text{C}}\right)=k\cdot t+C\$.

From there, remove the logarithm (both sides become powers of \$e\$) to find \$V_{_\text{C}}=\exp\left(C\right)\cdot\exp\left(k\cdot t\right)\$. Or just \$V_{_\text{C}}=A\cdot\exp\left(k\cdot t\right)\$. At \$t=0\$ you should have no problem figuring out what \$A\$ is. And you already know \$k\$.

With this in hand (knowing \$V_{_\text{C}}\left(t\right)\$), you can also just divide that by \$R_2\$ to work out any necessary currents.

It's not uncommon to see an assignment like \$\tau=R\,C\$. In this case, \$\tau=100\:\text{ms}\$. So you should expect to see a lot of important transition (about 2/3rds of it) taking place in the first \$100\:\text{ms}\$. By three or four time periods have gone by, there won't be much left to worry about. So if you wanted to plot a curve, you would not need more than 1/2 a second to cover anything important to show.

Comment: Okay, I got it I guess. Here is what I understand. We can apply both the derivative formula and simple V=I.R . I mean if we want to calculate Ic(t) on the capacitor (which is on the resistance at the same time) we can use the formula of  C.( d Vc(t)/dt ) . We can also use Vc(t)/ R formula. Is that right?

Comment: btw, I understood what is the reason for being -50V clearly. Thank you

Comment: @Computengineering The solution requires both views in order to form the KCL. You must know that the current in the resistor is \$\frac{V_{_\text{C}}}{R}\$ and also that the current in the capacitor is \$C\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_{_\text{C}}\$. It's not an either-or. The sum of these two currents must be zero.

Comment: Okay I completely understood what you said. Thank you so much :). Can you look at my last question? I  have just edited it. It is about the step response of an RC circuit